# Scheduler job on configurable time on Window Azure

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure

We have a **multi-tenant application** (being developed on Azure) where user can configure some events based on time(configurable to minute level).

We have to create some background running job that should fire all these events.
We are planning to create a worker role where main thread will provide tick event (`using Timer.tick`) every minute. Consumer of this thread will check if there are events configured at this time. if any event found, it will create multiple threads using Parallel library and then wait for those events to complete.

1. Is there any issue in approach proposed above? Can we improve it further?
2. Is there any PaaS offering which can be utilized to achieve the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out Azure Scheduler? See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/